# Monthly timeline grid with right to left horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a Horizontal Timeline Carousel in Bootstrap with Js I don't know where to start. The structure is something like below. Please help

[image]

Either I can do it with table column or with List Item. By clicking the arrow key the list scroll right to left with one month forward. I did not find and similar code around the internet.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" class=""><div class="stages ready" style="left: 0px;">
          <ul class="">
            <li data-stage-date="2018-07-01" class="ready" style="width: 480px; left: 0px;">
              <div class="interval"> <span class="title">July</span> </div>
              <div class="summary" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-weighted-open="₹0" data-won="₹0" data-value="₹0" data-weighted-summary="₹0" data-percentage="0">
                <div class="icon"> <span class="plus" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0">+</span>
                  <svg class="cui3-icon cui3-icon--s">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-sm-weighted" href="#icon-sm-weighted"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="number" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-summary="" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0"></span> </div>
                <div class="totalSum"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-stage-date="2018-08-01" class="ready" style="width: 480px; left: 480px;">
              <div class="interval"> <span class="title">August</span> </div>
              <div class="summary" data-open="100% of ₹10,000 " data-weighted-open="₹10,000" data-won="₹0" data-value="₹10,000" data-weighted-summary="₹10,000" data-percentage="100">
                <div class="icon"> <span class="plus" data-summary="₹10,000" data-weighted-open="₹10,000" data-open="100% of ₹10,000 " data-won="₹0">+</span>
                  <svg class="cui3-icon cui3-icon--s">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-sm-weighted" href="#icon-sm-weighted"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="number" data-summary="₹10,000" data-weighted-summary="" data-weighted-open="₹10,000" data-open="100% of ₹10,000 " data-won="₹0"></span> </div>
                <div class="totalSum"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-stage-date="2018-09-01" class="ready" style="width: 480px; left: 960px;">
              <div class="interval"> <span class="title">September</span> </div>
              <div class="summary" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-weighted-open="₹0" data-won="₹0" data-value="₹0" data-weighted-summary="₹0" data-percentage="0">
                <div class="icon"> <span class="plus" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0">+</span>
                  <svg class="cui3-icon cui3-icon--s">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-sm-weighted" href="#icon-sm-weighted"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="number" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-summary="" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0"></span> </div>
                <div class="totalSum"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-stage-date="2018-10-01" class="ready" style="width: 480px; left: 1440px;">
              <div class="interval"> <span class="title">October</span> </div>
              <div class="summary" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-weighted-open="₹0" data-won="₹0" data-value="₹0" data-weighted-summary="₹0" data-percentage="0">
                <div class="icon"> <span class="plus" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0">+</span>
                  <svg class="cui3-icon cui3-icon--s">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-sm-weighted" href="#icon-sm-weighted"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="number" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-summary="" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0"></span> </div>
                <div class="totalSum"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-stage-date="2018-11-01" class="ready" style="width: 480px; left: 1920px;">
              <div class="interval"> <span class="title">November</span> </div>
              <div class="summary" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-weighted-open="₹0" data-won="₹0" data-value="₹0" data-weighted-summary="₹0" data-percentage="0">
                <div class="icon"> <span class="plus" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0">+</span>
                  <svg class="cui3-icon cui3-icon--s">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-sm-weighted" href="#icon-sm-weighted"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="number" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-summary="" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0"></span> </div>
                <div class="totalSum"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-stage-date="2018-06-01" class="ready" style="width: 480px; left: -480px;">
              <div class="interval"> <span class="title">June</span> </div>
              <div class="summary" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-weighted-open="₹0" data-won="₹0" data-value="₹0" data-weighted-summary="₹0" data-percentage="0">
                <div class="icon"> <span class="plus" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0">+</span>
                  <svg class="cui3-icon cui3-icon--s">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-sm-weighted" href="#icon-sm-weighted"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="number" data-summary="₹0" data-weighted-summary="" data-weighted-open="₹0" data-open="0% of ₹0 " data-won="₹0"></span> </div>
                <div class="totalSum"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where is the image ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this some elements, but this time, I used ul(list).
You can use the scrollLeft (jQuery method), so your only work is that setting the new position properly.

```
$("scroll content(ul)").scrollLeft("100(new position)");
```

[For example](https://jsfiddle.net/dorj0byt/).
I hope this will help you.

**UPDATED**
Finally, I'll show you an example. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o39zn21r/)

You have `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`, so please solve this error at first. As long as JavaScript run without error, I can debug.

```
  ul.animate({
      ul.scrollLeft(ul.scrollLeft() + targetMonth.position().left - 15);
  }, 200);

  ↓

  ul.animate({
      scrollLeft: ul.scrollLeft() + targetMonth.position().left - 15
  }, 200);
```

***Finally***
First, Add some style and elements your `#date-list` to confirm working properly.

```
/* ADDED */
#date-list {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

<ul id="date-list" class="d-flex">
    <li id="month-1" class="list-group-item">...</li>
    <li id="month-2" class="list-group-item">...</li>
    <li id="month-3" class="list-group-item">...</li>
    <li id="month-4" class="list-group-item">...</li>
    <li id="month-5" class="list-group-item">...</li>
    <li id="month-6" class="list-group-item">...</li>
    <!-- ADDED -->
    <li id="month-7" class="list-group-item">...</li>
    <li id="month-8" class="list-group-item">...</li>
</ul>
```

Then, add a variable in init process and modify a logic.
(If you should handle properly when the number of `#date-list li` is not 12)
(But I assume at least you have eight item, because you have 'today' button.)

```
// ADDED in init process. 
var listCount = $("#date-list li").length;

// using it instead of hard cording.
 } else if (currentMonth === listCount) {
```

Now, You can see scrollbar, let't add a class in your css file.
(If you want to see the highlight where the list-item that you focus.)

```
.list-group-item.active-month {
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

Finally, if you don't want to show the default scroll bar, I think the best easy way is to use webkit-scrollbar, but unfortunately, that isn't working on IE.

```
#date-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /* Of course, you can also change the scrollbar what it looks. */
    display: none;
}
```

If you need to work only IE11 or Egde, I recommend [Perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar), or at leaset other plugins, rather than implement yourself.

If you need to work other version of IE, I can't help.(I don't have an environment.)

Here's [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vhL32b50/) using `perfect-scrollbar`.

Comment: This is what i want but i am using Bootstrap v3.3.6 so the list are coming horizontal is there any fix for this ? Also do i need popper.min.js ? Please suggest.

Comment: No, you don't need popper.min.js. I'm sorry confused you. Also, I updated my answer(add Bootstrap 3.3.6 version). Bootstrap v3~ simply don't have the classes related to the flex, but you know, Bootstrap is not a magic. They just use CSS3, and we can see its code. So it's the easy problem.

Comment: Thanks! Suppose I want only < Previous  | Current | Next > button so what would be the script ?

Comment: I mistook a lot in Bootstrap 3.3.6 version.(So I remove it).
Now, you want to implement a process 'prev, current, next'. This function should be easy if you understood JavaScript.
Let's think hard about it. You just need to control current state and showing the list item based on current state. (I updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks! I am getting TypeError: targetMonth.position(...) is undefined

Comment: Oh, really?, it seems IE can't use $(element).position. Chrome and Firefox is fine thought. If change the code 'scrollLeft: ul.scrollLeft() + targetMonth.offset().left - 119', is it work?. Since not using position, I can't explain calculation.

Comment: Hmm, Maybe, this is not a simple problem. if didn't work the above code, can you try it this code, 'ul.scrollLeft(ul.scrollLeft() + targetMonth.position().left - 15);' compromise on the animation.

Comment: This is my link and still not working could you please guide me http://webapplications.co.in/nextstepcrm/deal-timeline.html

Comment: Ok I fixed but same error "typeError: targetMonth.position(...)" plz check this link http://webapplications.co.in/nextstepcrm/deal-timeline.html

Comment: I implemented that logic to focus current of month(this month(8)) when you access the page. Now you don't have an element, which has id=month-8. That is the reason. The logic is this part `var monthOfToday = new Date().getMonth() + 1;`

Comment: But it seems you don't have a class for highlight current month.(So, nothing happen.) , Also, `$("#date-list")` is not allowed scrolling. if you want to use scroll bar but don't want to show it, Supporting IE<11 is difficult I think.

Comment: Just... just in case, I added some information for you. good luck.